# Why was the Altair numbered "8800" even though the processor was an 8080?

Tags: history, 8080, altair-8800

The Altair 8800 was a computer using the Intel 8080 processor.  **Why the difference in numbers?**

Comment: There was the Intel 8008, the Intel 8080. The number 8800 logically follows, perhaps?

Answer (score -4):

The name of the *complete package* (here a particular computer) has no relation to the name of the *parts* (here CPU). It may go as far as being legally risky to use the same name (moot if e.g. IBM or DEC did it with their CPUs and machines).

Comment: Your logic fails with the IMSAI 8080. Same CPU, one year later.

Comment: In practice, names of computers in the early x86 era often included part or all of the CPU name (e.g. Deskpro 286).

Comment: @Armand, "often included" is the point. Others had no relation whatsoever (IBM PC, Apple ][, ....).

Comment: @vonbrand I guess I'm not grasping your point here. I understood your answer's meaning to be "the name will never be related to the parts" - did you mean "the name will not necessarily be related to the parts"?